# sigma algebra for stochastic processes

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I'm trying to teach myself stochastic processes 'properly' following a very 'physicist' education.

I'm reasonably happy with most of the basics, but something I am tripping up on is the construction of (pushforward) probability spaces of functions on uncountable index sets (i.e. continuous time).

So let's say I have a stochastic process $\{X_t\}_{t\in T}$ on the underlying probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ (with samples $\omega$) which takes values in some state space $(S,\mathcal{S})$. My goal is to define/understand the law of the stochastic process $(\Omega_X,\mathcal{F}_X,P_X)$ and its relation to the product space $(S^T,\mathcal{S}^T)$.

Following Billingsley (Probability and Measure, Wiley), as I understand it, if one sets up the finite dimensional distributions

$$P_{1,\ldots,n}(X_{t_1}\in A_1,\ldots,X_{t_n}\in A_n)=P(\{\omega\in \Omega : X_{t_1}\in A_1,\ldots,X_{t_n}\in A_n\})$$

this implies the existence of a stochastic process via Kolmogorov's extension theorem (given consistency requirements etc.). However, the process is not fully defined unless you further define the nature of the paths in $X$. As I understand it we can do this with the finite dimensional distribution if we insist that the process is separable, which might mean restricting the space of functions to the set of continuous functions on $T$ (for example).

This tells me that I could have, for example if $(S,\mathcal{S})=(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ and then specify $\Omega_X=C[T,\mathbb{R}]\subset \mathbb{R}^T$, but when it comes to identifying the appropriate sigma algebra, $\mathcal{F}_X$, I realise I am missing something.

This is because, taking the above example, it is emphasised that whilst we must specify more precisely $\Omega_X$ to be $C[T,\mathbb{R}]$ in order to define the stochastic process, the continuous functions in $C[T,\mathbb{R}]$ *are not in* $\mathcal{B}^T$.

So my question(s) is (are) pragmatic:

I want to set up a stochastic process by defining its state space, the regularity of its paths and its finite dimensional distributions, I then get stuck at:

1. Say I wish to do the above for a measure on continuous functions such that $\Omega_x=C[T,\mathbb{R}]$, what is the sigma algebra, $\mathcal{F}_X$, which $P_X$ can assign probability to?
2. Say I wish to do the above for a measure on step functions (which are cadlag), here $\Omega_x$ is the space of all such step functions. What does the sigma algebra, $\mathcal{F}_X$, look like in this instance?

Fundamentally, I am confused as to why by taking a subset of the outcomes of the product space $S^T$ in order to properly define the stochastic process leads to the associated sigma algebras from that product space, $\mathcal{S}^T$, which is inadequate, and crucially do not know how to fix that.

What I didn't pick up in Billingsley, after he pointed out that these sigma algebras are inadequate (there is a section with this exact title), is what they should then be, I either didn't notice or understand when he explained this.

I am aware this is new to me so please do point out if this is incorrect to the point of being misleading and I will try to catch up.

Comment: Thanks. Trying to summarize and understand as I go. I get your first point, I think this is helpful. Would it be accurate to say, if $(S,\mathcal{S})=(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ we work with $(\Omega_x=C[T,\mathbb{R}],\mathcal{F}_X=\mathcal{B}^{T})$, but acknowledge that $\mathcal{F}_X$ does not contain *all* paths in $C[T,\mathbb{R}]$ so we are effectively defining a measure $P_X$ on all continuous functions in $C[T,\mathbb{R}]$ which are also in $\mathcal{B}^T$?

Comment: Sorry, just realized there was a bit of a hole in my argument. So, never mind. The question of path regularity is indeed a bit delicate, as any set in the product $\sigma$-algebra on $\Bbb R^T$ can only depend on countably many indices whereas talking about continuity depends on uncountably many such indices. Hence, when we talk about "almost sure continuity" we first have to restrict our attention to $\Bbb Q$ and then can talk about "modifying" our process at other points.

Comment: No worries. So is my statement that $C[T,\mathbb{R}]\subset \mathbb{R}^T$ incorrect? That would certainly explain my confusion (if not solve my problem).

Comment: It is correct that $C[T,\Bbb R] \subset \Bbb R^T$ and that it is not measurable in the product $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Ok. So that, in a nutshell, is 'my problem'. Surely, there must be a sigma algebra on $C[T,\mathbb{R}]$? Do we just say $\sigma(C[T,\mathbb{R}])$? Surely it has *something* to do with $\mathcal{B}^T$?

Comment: Of course there is. It is the Borel sigma algebra associated to the uniform topology on $C[T,\Bbb R]$, which coincides with the "product" sigma algebra generated by the maps $f \mapsto f(t)$ for $t\in \Bbb R$.

Comment: Please correct if untrue: so we no longer define measurable sets of paths using cylinder sets made from a *countable* number [this being the problem]) of times, but rather consider, for example, the set of all paths for which the metric (i.e. a single number for *the whole function*, as compared to some reference function) lies in some interval (i.e. the Borel sets)? And so for cadlag processes we analogously consider the Skorohod space with J1 metric meaning here the sigma algebra is the borel sigma algebra associated with the skorohod topology, i.e. borel sets of J1 metric?

Comment: To be completely clear, I don't really know what you mean by "It is the Borel sigma algebra associated to the uniform topology on $C[T,\mathbb{R}]$", my comment above is an attempt to step by step decode what this literally means. And the statement "coincides with the "product" sigma algebra generated by the maps..." confuses me more as it seems in direct contradiction to the idea that $\mathcal{S}^T$ doesn't contain what we need. What's the difference between the product sigma algebra using these maps (needs explaining) and the 'normal' product $\mathcal{S}^T$?

Comment: The Borel $\sigma$-algebra is the one generated by the open sets of the topology created by the uniform norm. This $\sigma$-algebra is much larger than $\mathcal B^T$ if we work on all of $\Bbb R^T$. However on $C[T,\Bbb R]$ this $\sigma$-algebra coincides with the one generated by the projection maps. So, the difference is that in the latter case we are only working on $C[T,\Bbb R]$ and not all of $\Bbb R^T$.